# convert english to arabic

Tags: javascript, translation

Hii,i m building a chat application.How to convert english to  arabic and display in arabic language.please help.

Comment: Do you mean translation or transliteration?

Comment: I think he actually means translation, I don't think you can transliterate English -> Arabic, only the other way around (I'm not sure though). If you mean actual translation, look at the Google language API: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/

Comment: Do you mean what the user types (which you could pass through Google Translate or similar), or the user interface (which you should use i18n if you want multiple languages in your UI).

Comment: Hello JeeBee ,thanks for your reply i want that when user writes in englisg in a text area ,then after submitting it shoud convert in arabic and displat in chat box in arabic in html

Answer (score 2):

Having used converters in the past, this worries me. Our people have enough trouble with misunderstanding each other without having a computer mistranslator helping the process.

Answer (score 2):

you need something like Yamli, http://www.yamli.com/editor/ar/i am not sure if they sell this teservice, or you can include it in your website...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Microsoft Translator API](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/ajax/) - it supports Arabic and is accessible via an AJAX call. There is a string translation example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576280.aspx).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

http://translate.google.com/

Works pretty well for English -> Dutch. I'm not sure about Arabic.

Otherwise pay someone who can speak English and Arabic for it.

Google translate also has an API available for JavaScript I guess.